# TurtleBot simulator does not launch properly

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, gazebo-simulator, ros-fuerte, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used VirtualBox ROS provided by NooTriX. When I launch TurtleBot simulator by typing

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch

it keeps showing a warning message

Warning [RaySensor.cc:206] ranges not constructed yet (zero sized)

and as a result, I cannot type anything. Then later, Gazebo closes by itself. Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50838/turtlebot-simulator-does-not-launch-properly/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I can type additional commands by opening a new terminal.

Sometimes Gazebo closes by itself especially when the motion is fast. But when I pause the motion, it will not close by itself. It suggests that the problem is related to display card or RAM ???

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [walker](https://answers.ros.org/users/53501/walker/) on 2020-04-13**:
My guess is memory.
I'm having the same problem. I'll start it myself.